# php not redirecting to my login_success.php page

Tags: php

Trying to make a login page using php following a tutorial, it's successfully logging in getting both the password and username from the database then showing echo "wrong password" and welcome for each scenario. However it doesnt redirect to my login_success.php page stays on check_login.php, heres my code for the check page:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; 
$username="root"; 
$password="root";
$db_name="test";
$tbl_name="members"; 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 


$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count > 0){
echo "Welcome";

session_register("myusername");

session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

any help would be great.

Comment: try commenting out `echo "Welcome";`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL);  
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` plus you're not calling `session_start();` which should most likely be in there. Plus, you'll most likely see an error stating `headers already sent in...` when adding error reporting.

Comment: It is because you cannot send headers *after* outputting something.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send anything to the client (i.e. `echo "Welcome";`) before setting your headers.

Reference http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Nor can you send anything to the client before starting sessions.